# Turning TV into touch screen

Tags: touchscreen, whiteboard

We have a 55" LCD TV that'll be hooked up to a computer. We'd like to turn it into some sort of touch screen where we can use it to whiteboard/annotate. What options do we have to accomplish this?

The only option I'm aware of is the [Polycom UC Board](http://www.polycom.com/products-services/hd-telepresence-video-conferencing/realpresence-accessories/realpresence-uc-whiteboard.html). Does anyone have any experience with this product? The things I don't like about it is that it's a closed ecosystem (for example, we can't use it to control a PC running e.g. [FuzeBox](https://www.fuzebox.com); we'd have to use Polycom's video conferencing/collaboration hardware), and it's also very expensive. Are there any alternatives out there?

We'd be using this system to provide a 24x7 video feed between two offices with multi-user meetings, do screen sharing, and whiteboarding/annotation using a stylus where the screens/whiteboards in both offices are synced in real-time.

If turning these TVs into a touch screens is not feasible (without using Polycom's products), I'd also be open to using tablets for annotating if that's an option.

Comment: "We have a 55" LCD TV that'll be hooked up to a TV" I assume you mean computer?

Comment: To me this is just a product request (which is off-topic).  You've found yourself a solution, try it and come back if you have problems with it.

Comment: Voted to close for the same reasons as @techie007.  You may be able to save your question to be more on-topic about how could you accomplish your end goal, rather than asking about specific product questions.  Just my $.02